# date-fns format does not format properly microSeconds?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I am using the following script in order convert microSeconds in hh:mm using
date-fns but I get the wrong formatting:

```js
const microSeconds = 100000000
format(addMilliseconds(new Date(0), microSeconds / 1000), 'hh:mm')}
```

for example in this case I would need to get '00:01' but instead I get `01:01`

Any idea how to fix it?

Runnable code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-cdgduf

Comment: Your script looks incomplete (`}... ?`). Could you please share runnable code and specify what is your expected output and what you are getting currently.

Comment: sorry guys, I made a mistake in my answer, now fixed and I have added an live example, thanks all for your feedback

Comment: Are you in +01:00 timezone?

Comment: yes, do you think it is relevant?

Comment: It seems so, [format's docs](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/format) say `Result may vary by locale`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `date-fns` format function relies on locales. [Format's docs](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/format) contains information (under table with accepted tokens):

> The result may vary by locale.

You could subtract timezone offset:

```
const d = new Date(0);
const formatedValue = format(
   addMilliseconds(new Date(0 + d.getTimezoneOffset()*1000*60), microSeconds / 1000), 'HH:mm')
```

Change also date format to `HH:mm`, because `hh` is between 01 and 12

Answer (score 0):

According to this example:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
const formatedValue = format(0, 'hh:mm')
// output: 01:00
```

You should not use `date-fns` to just convert a duration into a human-readable `string` since it always depends on timezones. You should implement your own format function since it's basic dividing and multiplying.

Working example =>
https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-whz5tg?file=app.ts

Comment: No, I did not.  Since we are a big community who everyone wants to help each other I just post something if I have directly an idea. And this looks like he just converts micro to milli wrongly.

Comment: Then why did you posted it as answer even if you have not tested yourself? Better to post such as comments only. Post your answer with runnable and tested code

Comment: Well, that's a point where I could agree. But OP has written `any ideas?`. I think this is ok as an answer .

Comment: runnable example https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-cdgduf